# how to set properties file path in shell script

Tags: java, shell

how to set the path of  Properties file  along with Java command in a shell script which is running the main class i ma using this:

```
java -cp %classpath% -Doligosoft.POSConfig.file="/home/mlpc04/Paritosh/Workspace/POS_3.0 resources/posconfig.properties"com.floreantpos.main.Main
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your classpath with a new one, which owns the properties file.
If your properties file is in the root of your classpath it could be used from your Java program using something like this:

```
Someclass.class.getResourceAsStream(posconfig.properties)
```

For example your new classpath could be something like this:

```
OLDCLASSPATH:/home/mlpc04/Paritosh/Workspace/POS_3.0 resources/
```

By the way: you said you are using a shell script. I do not know what kind of shell you are using but %classpath% sounds like a DOS SCRIPT (Windows) and your path looks like a Linux one where I doubt you are going to use a DOS SCRIPT.

Comment: Sir I have updated the class path with the location of the properties file which is in resources folder of my project,but again i m getting the same null pointer exception with respect to the file in my shell script i wrote like:
"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/java" -cp  $CLASSPATH -Doligosoft.POSconfig.file=/home/mlpc04/Paritosh/POS_3.0/resources/posconfig.properties com.floreantpos.main.Main is this the correct way please can u suggest

Comment: Sorry, work does not leave me too much free time... It depends on what kind of null pointer exception you are getting and how are you trying to open the properties file. If you have the properties file in your classpath (IMHO) something like this: -Doligosoft.POSconfig.file=posconfig.properties would be enough. But it depends on how are you trying to use that properties file.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the program you are using expect the properties file to be communicated to it.

It could be in the classpath directly.

Or it could be done via a command line argument like you shown in your question
Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3457999/592898